# Divide y-axis values by 10 onclick

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Ok so I'm using highcharts and jquery. I have some sample code for a chart and a button here. What I want to do is click on the button and have the y-axis data all divide by 10 as well as change the y-axis title to append (/10) so the user knows the values have changed. Is this possible? If so how? 
Thanks so much in advance :)

Edit: See bottom for JSfiddle

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height Versus Weight of 507 Individuals by Gender'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Heinz  2003'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'Height (cm)'
            },
            startOnTick: true,
            endOnTick: true,
            showLastLabel: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Weight (kg)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: 5,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    }
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Female',
            color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
            data: [[161.2, 51.6], [167.5, 59.0], [159.5, 49.2], [157.0, 63.0], [155.8, 53.6],
                [170.0, 59.0], [159.1, 47.6], [166.0, 69.8], [176.2, 66.8], [160.2, 75.2],
                [172.5, 55.2], [170.9, 54.2], [172.9, 62.5], [153.4, 42.0], [160.0, 50.0],
                [147.2, 49.8], [168.2, 49.2], [175.0, 73.2], [157.0, 47.8], [167.6, 68.8],
                [159.5, 50.6], [175.0, 82.5], [166.8, 57.2], [176.5, 87.8], [170.2, 72.8],
                [174.0, 54.5], [173.0, 59.8], [179.9, 67.3], [170.5, 67.8], [160.0, 47.0],
                [154.4, 46.2], [162.0, 55.0], [176.5, 83.0], [160.0, 54.4], [152.0, 45.8],
                [162.1, 53.6], [170.0, 73.2], [160.2, 52.1], [161.3, 67.9], [166.4, 56.6],
                [168.9, 62.3], [163.8, 58.5], [167.6, 54.5], [160.0, 50.2], [161.3, 60.3]]

        }]
    });
});
```

JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mPY8z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go! Loops through each point, updates it's y co-ord by dividing by 10, then appends the title of the y axis!

```
var divide=1;
$( "#buttonDiv" ).click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var data = chart.series[0].data;
    if (data.length) {
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
        {
            var point = data[i];
            point.update(point.y/=10);
        }
        divide*=10;
        chart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
            text: 'Weight (kg)/'+divide
        });
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPY8z/1/)

Comment: Could you tell me how to update the X-axis in the same way please? I can't seem to get the co-ordinates to change accordingly :(

Comment: For the x-axis it needs to be an array, like this `point.update([point.x/=10,point.y]);`